# Orient DB - Storing linked data into Orient DB using Java with links

Tags: java, json, hashmap, orientdb

What im working with is obtaining data container from Orient db(server) and store it inside local orient db and then use it in the later stages of the program.

I have the following jsonObject which was obtained from server orient db:

```
{
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#95:0",
        "@version": 3,
        "@class": "demo1_OnlineShopping",
        "product": [
            {
                "@type": "d",
                "@rid": "#97:0",
                "@version": 3,
                "@class": "demo1_MobilePhone",
                "operatingSystem": "Android",
                "condition": "",
                "minPrice": "100",
                "maxPrice": "500",
                "keyword": "Galaxy S5",
                "brand": "Samsung"
            },
            {
                "@type": "d",
                "@rid": "#97:3",
                "@version": 1,
                "@class": "demo1_MobilePhone",
                "operatingSystem": "Android",
                "condition": null,
                "minPrice": "5",
                "maxPrice": "300",
                "keyword": "M8",
                "brand": "HTC"
            }
        ],
        "user": {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#100:0",
            "@version": 1,
            "@class": "demo1_User",
            "password": "jamesgillespy@suremail.info",
            "email": "1qaz2wsx@"
        },
        "maxAllowance": "350",
        "cart": null,
        "lookingFor": "Mobile Phone",
        "@fieldTypes": "product=z"
    }
```

Im converting this into a hashmap using the below code to store it inside the local db:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            map = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>(){});
```

Then im storing it into the local orient database using the below code:

```
ODocument doc = new ODocument("Person");
        for(Entry<String, Object> entry : hashmap.entrySet()){
            doc.field( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        doc.save();
```

My 1st problem is,its not allowing to store the values starting with @ like "@type", "@class" etc. It throws exception.When i remove them it works. And then another problem occurs, those are not linked inside the local db. It stores as one data container where there must be links with multiple data container. I assume it is because "@class" wasnt there. And creating the db name(Person) manually while inserting seems wrong. Any links or code will help. Thanks in advance.